# How to remove difference between appearance of font present in styleddocument and html document of jtextpane?

Tags: jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I am using `jtextpane` with default editorkit. Once user input the text, it is saved as **html in text** file using **html editor** kit and **buffered output stream**. But when i acces the file using another program which is using `jtexteditor`, file text along with text size, color and family is retrieved successfully but there is difference b/w font styles. Eg. When using **calibri**, then some characters are too bold and others are normal.

How to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: show us what you have done so far, this would help you to get answer quickly.

Comment: There is a kind of bug with font size in the JTextPane with HTML. There is a kind of weird conversion between attributes, especially font size. I'm on my phone and can't answer now but check my questions on the subject

Comment: But some fonts like Segoe Print are displayed same as in textpane, but for Calibri, arial appearance become weird.

Comment: Could you show a short self contained correct example that shows exactly the problem?